# Perl Net::OAuth2 example code

Tags: perl, authentication, oauth

Need example code (yes, I have gone through the CPAN docs) to authenticate using [`Net::OAuth2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OAuth2)

I have the following:

- consumer key
- consumer secret
- access key
- access secret

P.S. I believe generally, you provide the consumer key and secret and receive an access key and secret, but in this case, I already have them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the SYNOPSIS in the POD for [Net::OAuth2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOAuth2), which you have already looked at, does the code in the test directory help?

[t/01-client.t](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KGRENNAN/Net-OAuth2-0.06/t/01-client.t)

If not, you could contact the module author via the email address in the POD and ask for an example.